# How do I include negative decimal numbers in this regular expression?

Tags: regex, numbers

How do I match negative numbers as well by this regular expression?  This regex works fine with positive values, but I want it to also allow negative values e.g. -10, -125.5 etc.

```
^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/

Comment: i tried adding [-] at the start but this did not work. i also tried a combination of small changes

Comment: try this ^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$

Answer (score 253, accepted):

You should add an optional hyphen at the beginning by adding `-?` (`?` is a [**quantifier**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) meaning *one or zero occurrences*):

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

I verified it in Rubular with these values:

```
10.00
-10.00
```

and both matched as expected.

```js
let r = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/);

//true
console.log(r.test('10'));
console.log(r.test('10.0'));
console.log(r.test('-10'));
console.log(r.test('-10.0'));
//false
console.log(r.test('--10'));
console.log(r.test('10-'));
console.log(r.test('1-0'));
console.log(r.test('10.-'));
console.log(r.test('10..0'));
console.log(r.test('10.0.1'));
```

Comment: you should escape the dot, i.e. `^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`

Comment: If there is a potential to need to capture explicitly possitive numbers (+10.00, used in some applications) you could use `^[-+]?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`

Comment: why not replacing `[0-9]\d*` with `\d+`? so `^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$`?

Comment: And do you even need the group? `^[-+]?\d*.?\d*$` matches `3`, `3.`, `0.3`, and `.3`. Might be more useful depending on the application (e.g. input validation).

Answer (score 166):

Some Regular expression examples:

**Positive Integers**:

```
^\d+$
```

**Negative Integers**:

```
^-\d+$
```

**Integer**:

```
^-?\d+$
```

**Positive Number**:

```
^\d*\.?\d+$
```

**Negative Number**:

```
^-\d*\.?\d+$
```

**Positive Number or Negative Number**:

```
^-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+$
```

**Phone number**:

```
^\+?[\d\s]{3,}$
```

**Phone with code**:

```
^\+?[\d\s]+\(?[\d\s]{10,}$
```

**Year 1900-2099**:

```
^(19|20)[\d]{2,2}$
```

**Date** (dd mm yyyy, d/m/yyyy, etc.):

```
^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\D([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])\D(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])$
```

**IP v4**:

```
^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}$
```

Comment: The first example for positive integers `^\d+$` includes zero, but 0 is neither positive nor negative. For positive non-zero integers, try `^[1-9]\d*$`

Answer (score 14):

I don't know why you need that first `[0-9]`.

Try:

```
^-?\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

**Update**

If you want to be sure that you'll have a digit on the ones place, then use

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: Probably just to guarantee a digit in the ones place, `^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$` should work if that's the case

Answer (score 10):

Adding `"-" minus` followed by `? quantifier` in front of `[0-9] expression` should do the work.

**`-?[0-9]`**

**For reference**

- `^b` - `^ quantifier` matches for any string begin with "b"
- `c?` - `? quantifier` matches for 0 or 1 occurrence of "c"
- `[0-9]` - find any character between the `[] brackets`
- `\d` - find a digit from `0-9`
- `d*` - `* quantifier` matches for zero or more occurrence of "d"
- `\.` - matches a `"." character`
- `z+` - `+ quantifier` matches for one or more occurrence of "z"
- `e$` - `$ quantifier` matches for any string end with "e"

*Hope, it'll help to understand posted regex in the question*.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED(13/08/2014):** This is the best code for positive and negative numbers =)

```
(^-?0\.[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*$)|(^-?[1-9]+[0-9]*((\.[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*$)|(\.[0-9]+)))|(^-?[1-9]+[0-9]*$)|(^0$){1}
```

I tried with this numbers and works fine:

```
-1234454.3435
-98.99
-12.9
-12.34
-10.001
-3
-0.001
-000
-0.00
0
0.00
00000001.1
0.01
1201.0000001
1234454.3435
7638.98701
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a case recently where students were entering only the accepted characters in a numeric response field, yet still managed to break things. Thus, I ended up using the following catch-all.

`^[+-]?((\d*\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*))$`

This ensures everything that *should* work *will* work, including:

```
0
.0
0.0
-.11
+.2
-0.2
+01.
-123.
+123.4567890
-012.0
+1
-1.
```

The expression also rejects things that mischievous kids might enter which, while still being valid character input, would not be a valid number, such as:

```
+.
-
.
(nul or newline)
```

I found that the expression as most have it written here (ending with `\d+$`) will reject numbers if they include a decimal point without any numbers after it. And making that expression instead end with `\d*` would make the entire expression optional, thus causing it to match the entries in the second list above. But by using the capturing group with the boolean `OR` operator (`|`) to require at least one digit either after ***or before*** a decimal point, all bases are covered.

Answer (score 2):

This will allow a `-` or `+` character only when followed by a number:

```
 ^([+-](?=\.?\d))?(\d+)?(\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 2):

I have some experiments about regex in django url, which required from negative to positive numbers

```
^(?P<pid>(\-\d+|\d+))$
```

Let's we focused on this `(\-\d+|\d+)` part and ignoring others, this semicolon `|` means **OR** in regex, then the negative value will match with this `\-\d+` part, and positive value into this `\d+`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, [allowing both negative and positive numbers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eed0a8cf-317a-44a2-bf84-5f30c86a8a91/regular-expression-to-allow-negative-and-positive-numbers?forum=winappswithcsharp):

```
 \-*\d+
```

If using C#:

```
Regex.Match(someString, @"\-*\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have this `val="-12XXX.0abc23"` and you want to extract only the decimal number, in this case this regex (`^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`) will not help you to achieve it.
 this is the proper code with the correct detection regex:

```js
var val="-12XXX.0abc23";
val = val.replace(/^\.|[^-?\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will allow both positive and negative integers

> ValidationExpression="^-?[0-9]\d*(\d+)?$"

Answer (score 1):

```
^[+-]?\d{1,18}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

accepts positive or negative decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a 0 or 1 token:

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(.\d+)?$
```

Comment: Andre beat me to it, he's right too, no need for the [0-9] token.

Answer (score 0):

For negative number only, this is perfect.

```
^-\d*\.?\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for number, optional decimal point, optional negative:

```
^-?(\d*\.)?\d+$;
```

works for negative integer, decimal, negative with decimal

Answer (score 0):

```
^(-?\d+\.)?-?\d+$
```

allow:

```
23425.23425
10.10
100
0
0.00
-100
-10.10
10.-10
-10.-10
-23425.23425
-23425.-23425
0.234
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `/\d/` works as expected for all cases I can think of:

```js
let ns = {
  regex: {
    num: /\d/
  }
}

for (let i of [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 'one', 'negative one', Math.PI, Math.E, (42 * -1), (42 / -1), '-1', '0', '1', 1.01, -1.01, .1, -.1, Math.sqrt(42)]) {
  console.log(ns.regex.num.test(i) + ': ' + i);
}
```

For more `Math` fun, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math