# Javascript regex to allow negative numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regex to allow floating point numbers

```
str.replace(/(\.\d\d)\d+|([\d.]*)[^\d.]/, '$1$2')
```

I need to allow negative numbers also. Any ideas.

This allows 123.45 and it wont allow the chars like 123.45a. I need to allow -123.45. Currently its not allowing me to enter negative numbers

Comment: provide some inputs along with expected outputs.

Comment: What about adding this in front of your regex? (-|) It will match a minus or nothing.

Comment: Do you *need* to use a RegEx? There are better ways in JS to validate numbers

Comment: Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted that best solves your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a shorter regex that matches negative floats:

```
/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/
```

[Explaination and demo of this regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/pN0rH9/1)

If you want to match explicitly positive numbers like `+123.123` along with the negative ones, use the following regex:

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15814655/586051)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
(?!=\A|\s)(-|)[\d^]*\.[\d]*(?=\s|\z)
```

It will match all floating point numbers. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lE3gV5/2

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
str.replace(/-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/g,'')

                 OR 

str.match(/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Regex:

```
parseFloat(str.replace(/.*?(\-?)(\d*\.\d+)[^\d\.]*/, '$1$2'));
```

But its better to match the number than replace the other characters:

```
var matches = /(\-?\d*\.(?:\d+)?)/.exec(str);
if (typeof matches != 'undefined' && matches.length > 0) {
    var num = parseFloat(matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: dot not allowed in this first regex

Comment: Your provided test input works with the first regex. Can you provide me the not working input string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regexp:

`/-?(\d+\.\d+)[^\w\.]/g`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sQ9mX1/2)