# how to get this regex to also accept negative values

Tags: c#, regex

I have no knowledge of regular expressions and find the documentations so hard to understand.
Currently I use this expression

```
@"\d+(\R.\d{0,2})?"
```

It only allows decimals which is what I want but it does not allows negative numbers.

I found this question about the same subject :
[How do I include negative decimal numbers in this regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression)
but I just cannot see what I need to change in my expression to get it working.

I would appreciate some help with this.
If there is some documentation on the subject that is clear to read and understand that would also be nice.

Comment: include `-` as `@"-?\d+(\R.\d{0,2})?" `

Comment: works perfect, thanks

Comment: Why is there a `\R` in the regexp? That is a newline. You should probably remove that. Apart from that @rock321987 is correct: `-?` means "0 or 1 minus character".

Comment: I dont know why its in there, i found this expression from a support ticket from devexpress. I will remove it and check if everything still works

Comment: without the \R it allows the user to type one non numerical character, so it seems i do need it

Answer (score 2):

Use `^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`, but your regex allows numbers like `20.` so i suggest to chage it at least for this one `^-?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`.

Also don't forget the `^` and the `$`. You can use [www.regex101.com/](https://www.regex101.com/), where you can try regex and watch a good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you can include the  `-` as
`@"[+-]?\d+(\R.\d{0,2})?"`

[Check this simple Cheat sheet for C# regular expressions metacharacters, operators, quantifiers etc](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet)
and For sure   https://regex101.com is the best place Online regex tester