# Regex getting amount from string without currency symbol

Tags: regex

I need to extract the amount from a string removing the currency.
e.g.

I want an output of -5.95 or 6.85

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy -$5.95 dog. 
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy $6.85 dog.
```

meaning both possitive or negative amount should be accepted but remove the $ sign.

I use this pattern

```
([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)
```

however it only gets the positive amount.
-$5.95 was extracted as 5.95.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the minus symbol.

```
-?\$[0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*
```

The `?` after the `-` at the beginning makes the minus symbol optional.

The `\$` matches a dollar sign and must be escaped with a backslach `\` since a dollar sign is significant in regex.

Rather than try to use regex to extract the value, you could do a simple string replace on the dollar sign after you've matched the price.

```
match(/-?\$[0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*/).replace('$', '')
// -15.27
```

Additionally, your decimal number expression could use some cleanup.

```
-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

The above `( )?` is an optional group.

Inside it, the `\.` means a single decimal is required. A `.` must be escaped with a backslash `\` since a `.` will normally match any character.

Next, one or more numbers must be matched.

This approach prevents values like `1.` from being matched since the decimal must be followed by at least one number.

Comment: Thanks but what if the amount has dollar sign like this -$5.95? I believe it will only work if the amount is -5.95

Comment: Cool my problem now is that currency is dynamic, is there a way in which you will remove any text or character between negative and the number?

Comment: @valrecx You should ask a new question then.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is only checking for a number, period and another number. You would have to add a check for a hyphen.

For example:
`-?[0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*`

You can see a similar issue at [How do I include negative decimal numbers in this regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15814592/3312597)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried both with negative and positive, but if there is a $ sign in the middle it don't extract it.

Comment: Please don't use answers as comments/replies. If you take out the "have you tried" part and replace it with an actual regex it would be better.