# Capture negative dollar values

Tags: python, regex, string

the following expression captures positive dollar values i.e. 400$
how can i modify this to capture negative values only.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+\$$')
```

Comment: Use `r'^-\d+\$$'`, add `-` after `^`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15814681/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pattern = re.compile(r'^-\d+\$$')`
You just need to add a `-` sign in there.