# Python Regex - optional match, do not capture one match

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, optional-parameters

I'm trying to find an elegant way for matching negative and positive numbers at the same time, but not to capture the + sign while capturing the - sign.

So I have something like:

```
re.findall("([+-] \d+)x", "6x2 + 4x + 5 - 2x2 - 7x + 4 + 87x - 100x")
```

This gives me all multipliers for x, both positive and negative (great!). I would like the negative numbers to be `- 2`, for example, but not return the plus sign for positive numbers (`4` instead of `+ 4`). I failed with `?:` option, maybe I just used it incorrectly.

Comment: `-?\d+` should be sufficient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include negative decimal numbers in this regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression)

Comment: @emsimpson92 Unfortunately, no. I need the minus signs, but not the plus signs. This doesn't return the minus sign either.

Comment: yes it does. If there is a space between them, use `-?\s*\d+`

Comment: @user10334946 Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a positive and lookahead and lookbehind:

`(?<=\+) \d+(?=x)|- \d+(?=x)`

```
print(re.findall("(?<=\+) \d+(?=x)|- \d+(?=x)", "6x2 + 4x + 5 - 2x2 - 7x + 4 + 87x - 100x"))
# [' 4', '- 2', '- 7', ' 87', '- 100']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0HZZ0U/1/) | [Python demo](https://rextester.com/FSWL12008)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\+) \d+(?=x)` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is a `+`, then match a space followed by one or more digits. Use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right side is an `x`
- `|` Or
- `- \d+(?=x)` Match `-`, a space and one or more digits. Then use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is an `x`

If you don't want to include the space before the match without the `+` you could remove it before the digit and add it to the positive lookbehind:

`(?<=\+ )\d+(?=x)|- \d+(?=x)`