# format data.table column values (row wise) if numeric

Tags: r, data.table

I am creating a summary `data.table` to be inserted in a `knitr` report using `xtable`. I would like to check each row value in each column if `is.numeric() == TRUE` and if it is, format the number, then revert it back to a character. If `is.numeric() == FALSE` then return the value. The actual `data.table` may have many columns.

Here's what I have below, with the desired output at the bottom:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

dt <- data.table(A = c("apples",
                       "bananas",
                       1000000.999),
                 B = c("red",
                       5000000.999,
                       0.99))

dt

a <- dt[, lapply(.SD,
                 function(x)  {
                   if (is.na(is.numeric(x))) {
                     prettyNum(as.numeric(x), digits = 0, big.mark = ",")
                   } else {
                     x
                   }
                 })]

a

b <- dt[, A := ifelse(is.na(is.numeric(A)),
                      format(as.numeric(A), digits = 0, big.mark = ","),
                      A)] %>% 
  .[, B := ifelse(is.na(is.numeric(B)),
                  format(as.numeric(B), digits = 0, big.mark = ","),
                  B)]

b
b


desired <- data.table(A = c("apples",
                            "bananas",
                            "1,000,000"),
                      B = c("red",
                            "5,000,000",
                            "1"))

desired
```

From my understanding `lapply` in the `j` argument of `data.table` syntax operates on the vector, so it can be used for functions like `mean()`, `sum()`, `na.approx()`, etc. and wouldn't necessarily work here. But I would like to loop over each column in the `data.table` without specifying each column name since there could be many columns and naming them would be cumbersome. It's kind of like I know the circle doesn't go in the square but I really want it to!

I tried the `:= ifelse()` approach which I thought should work, but it seems to be returning the first element. On a different `data.table` where the column is entirely numeric, employing the same approach yields all `NA`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To be clear: your `data.table` is completely `character`, and you want to format them different *if they can be converted to numbers*, is that right? Why aren't they numbers to begin with?

Comment: It is a `data.table`to be put into a report potentially containing both characters and numbers. A column might contain a service provider name, a date, costs (which I would like formatted as they would be 'numeric'), etc. This `data.table` would strictly be a summary `data.table` for a report, no analysis is performed on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `set` with `number`.  Loop through the sequence of columns with a `for` loop, identify the index of elements that are all digits or `.` ('i1'), use that as the `i` in `set`, convert those elements to `numeric`, apply the `number` to set the `format` for that element

```
library(scales)
library(data.table)
for(j in seq_along(dt)) {
  i1 <- grep("^[0-9.]+$", dt[[j]])
  set(dt, i = i1, j = j, value = number(as.numeric(dt[[j]][i1]), big.mark = ","))
 }
dt
#          A         B
#1:    apples       red
#2:   bananas 5,000,001
#3: 1,000,001         1
```

Comment: If I have negative numbers, will that `for loop` change? I'm guessing in the `grep` argument? I'm seeing what I can find now. I have a column with positive and negative values. All the positive values are formatted correctly, but the negative are not.

Comment: I did indeed find it, I fired off the comment too quickly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression

Comment: @Prevost Glad to know that you find the pattern