# Angular 8 : Make FormBuilder Accept Numbers Only with Range for Latitude and Longitude

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

How do I get FormBuilder to require numbers?

I am writing a Formbuilder for Latitude and Longitude.
In this below,

- Writing -91 or 91 will give Validation errors, working as expected
- Anything between -90 and 90 works which is good.
- It accepts numbers up to 32 digits and decimal points, also working

Problem:

- However typing in Letters 'Abcd' etc, does Not give validation errors.

How can this be resolved?

```
  'latitude': [null, [Validators.maxLength(32), Validators.min(-90), Validators.max(90)]],
```

Prefer to have validation in form, rather than input textbox type=number if possible,

Comment: Doesn't come out of the box, but you could write a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators). FYI, scalable form validation is HARD - I highly recommend [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)

Comment: hi @Adam  wow , so min and max come out of box, but not number validation? thanks

Comment: Side Note: It might be worth opening a GitHub issue with the angular team. Min/Max should infer that a number is required. Any non-number should make the validator fail. Sounds like a bug. But, as Muhammed mentioned, setting `type="number"` would prevent users from entering text.

Comment: use [ng2-validation](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation) for simple validation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use input type number this will block any letters

```
<input type="number" formControlName="latitude" />
```

another option to use Validators.pattern to allow only number this will set the control to invalid if you have entered invalid characters.

```js
   latitude: [
        null,
        [
          Validators.maxLength(32),
          Validators.min(-90),
          Validators.max(90),
          Validators.pattern(/\-?\d*\.?\d{1,2}/)
        ]
      ]
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qs7puv)

Comment: like this for the integer number `Validators.pattern(`^[0-9]*$`)`

Comment: They don't have a validator for numbers (https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators). Use the `pattern` validator and provide the proper regex (^ Muhammed mentioned it above)

Comment: @MattSmith74 check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional/12117060

Comment: I have update the answer can be more helpful and include a demo 

Comment: hi Muhammed, just remember needs to work with negative answers, I'm applying this /\-?\d*\.?\d{1,2}/

Comment: You just need to include the - character in front  check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with [ng2-validation](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation) library

```
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';
```

> range

```
new FormControl('', CustomValidators.range([10, 20]))
```

> digits

```
 new FormControl('', CustomValidators.digits)
```

Use it as

```
latitude: [null,
           [CustomValidators.digits,CustomValidators.range([-90, 90])]         
          ]
```

Comment: we are using Angular 8, but will try this

Comment: You can use it with Angular 8, I'm using it in my Angular 6 project