# jquery regular expression (allow minus, digits, dot)

Tags: javascript, regex

Need help with regular expression in jquery.
This piece of code allows only one dot and numbers to enter, but it is necessary to let minus pass at the beginning (for negative values)

```
$(function(){
    $('.number_dots').on('input', function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^\.|[^\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
    });
});
```

SOLVED
The solution:

```
$(function(){
    $('.number_dots').on('input', function(){
        //this.value = this.value.replace(/^\.|[^\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');

        var value = this.value;
        value = value.trim();
        //If minus symbol occur at the beginning
        if(value.charAt(0) === '-'){
            value = value.substring(1, value.length);
            value = "-"+value.replace(/^\.|[^\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
        }else{
            value = value.replace(/^\.|[^\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
        }
        console.log(value);
        this.value = value;
    });
});
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression

Comment: Your regex is replacing the old dot with the new one and removes the old one. Is this the functionality you created?

Comment: You solution is static and not practical check my answer, I modified it.

Answer (score 2):

This regex (`^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`) to match the correct +/- decimal, and for removing incorrect extra digits use the following code.

```js
var val="-12XXX.0abc23";
val = val.replace(/^\.|[^-?\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
console.log(val);
```

Comment: You answer didnt remove charaters eg `value = '-423dsd423.44'`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code

```
var value = '-423423.44';
value = value.trim();
//If minus symbol occur at the beginning
if(value.charAt(0) === '-'){
    value = value.substring(1, value.length);
    value = "-"+value.replace(/^\.|[^\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
}else{
    value = value.replace(/^\.|[^\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
}
console.log(value);
```

Comment: this is static coding, not a solution my friend

Comment: But for a negative number, It will always comes in the beggining.

Comment: so why not to use `-?` at the beginning of the regex !!

Comment: @Basil Agree with you, I have added one alternate possibility only