# String refindall

Tags: python, valueerror, findall

```py
import re
s = "  afd [asd] 12  [a34] [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
nums = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'[^\w]\d+', s)]
print(nums)

----

import re
def integers_in_brackets(s):
  
nums = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'[^\w]\d+', s)]
print(nums)
    

def main():
     
    print(integers_in_brackets("  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why this causes "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[12'" when I divide it to 2 functions?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches characters before the number as well - i.e. `[^\w]` will match non-digit characters.

You should *capture* just the numeric component - using parentheses.

Try this:

```
nums = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'[^\w](\d+)', s)]
```

Comment: thank you, this almost works!  I need also negative values. what should i add so -43 doesnt change to 43?

Comment: Make the `-` [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression).

Answer (score 0):

> Why this causes "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[12'" when I divide it to 2 functions?

Because you didn't just refactor your code into two functions the input is different.

At first, your input was `"  afd [asd] 12  [a34] [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"`

Next, your input is `"  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"`

Your second input has square brackets and a space wrapping the first "12". If this change in input is intentional, then it is a matter of fixing your regex  (but I can't do so because I can't tell the intent of the regex or possible inputs).